# Are Azure AD limits and quotas also applicable to Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am somehow confused with B2C limis and restrictions article.

On one hand, we have an atricle specifying AD B2C limits here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/service-limits. This article also say "See also Azure AD service limits and restrictions" which are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-service-limits-restrictions

Are AD limits also enforced in AD B2C? All of them? Some of them? None of them?

In particular, I want to know if

- AD limit of 300 000 resources also applies to B2C
- AD limit of 5 000 dynamic groups also applies to B2C
- Schema extensions: AD limit of 100 values 256 characters maximum each also applies

Answer (score 1):

- AD limit of 300 000 resources also applies to B2C - **Does not apply**
- AD limit of 5 000 dynamic groups also applies to B2C - **Does not apply, dynamic groups are unavailable in B2C**
- Schema extensions: AD limit of 100 values 256 characters maximum each also applies - **Applies**